# Gradle wrapper problem with ionic 4 when running on android

Tags: ionic-framework

`java.lang.NullPointerException` when building android

Already try removing and adding android again

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova run android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Here is ionic info

Ionic:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (I:\ionic\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2
```

Cordova:

```
 cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 4 other plugins)
```